# Picture With Text

Tags: image-manipulation

How do I make a Script that will add a yellow Box containing text beneath a picture? and have it saved as a Jpeg?

Are there any Programs that I can use to script this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php.